# Max $z = x_1(1-x_2)x_3$ s.t. $x_1 - x_2 + x_3 \le 1$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mathematical-modeling, operations-research, dynamic-programming

Using dynamic programming,

> Maximise $$z = x_1(1-x_2)x_3$$
>
> subject to
>
> $$x_1 - x_2 + x_3 \le 1$$
>
> $$x_1, x_2, x_3 \ge 0$$

---

Here's the outline of my solution 1. How is it?

Let $y_2=1-x_2$.

Also let's change the other x's to y's.

Then we have

> Maximise $$z = y_1y_2y_3$$
>
> subject to
>
> $$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 \le 2$$
>
> $$y_1, \color{red}{y_2,} y_3 \ge 0$$
>
> $$y_2 \le 1$$

We can deduce that $y_2 \ge 0$, but do we need to? In this case I guess not, but in general?

If we solve this problem by dynamic programming, then we get the same answer as in Wolfram.

---

Here's the outline of my solution 2. How is it?

Stage 3: Max $x_3$

$$f_3^{*}(s_3) = \max_{0 \le x_3 \le s_3}\{x_3\}$$

Stage 2: Min $x_2$

$$f_2^{*}(s_2) = \color{red}{\min}_{0 \le x_2 \color{red}{\le s_2}}\{(1-x_2)f_3^{*}(s_2+x_2)\}$$

Stage 1: Max $x_1$

$$f_1^{*}(s_1) = \max_{0 \le x_1 \le s_1}\{(x_1)f_2^{*}(s_1 - x_1)\}|_{s_1 = 1}$$

After we solve $x_1^{*} = 2/3$,

we get

$$x_2^{*} = s_2 = s_1 - x_1^{*} = 1 - 2/3 = 1/3,$$

$$x_3^{*} = s_2+x_2^{*} = 1/3 +  1/3 = 2/3$$

---

1. I think we have to **minimise** $x_2$ and maximise everything else because the $x_2$ part we want to maximise is $1-x_2$, which would be done by minimising $x_2$. Is that right?
2. Why should we still have $x_2 \color{red}{\le s_2}$? My solution (whose answer agrees with Wolfram) seems to rely on $x_2^{*} = s_2$.

I was thinking that the **negative coefficient of $x_2$ in the constraint removes that**.

If not, what is the role of the negative coefficient of $x_2$ (in the constraint, not objective function)? Just the $s_2 \color{red}{+} x_2$?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to assume $1-x_2\ge0$, as otherwise $z$ would be negative. By AM-GM, one has $\sqrt[3]{x_1(1-x_2)x_3}\le\frac{x_1+1-x_2+x_3}3\le 2/3$. The equality case is $x_1=1-x_2=x_3=2/3$

Comment: Okay that makes sense to assume, but did I seem to or actually not assume it in some way?

Comment: Nope, in order for AM-GM to work, I need $1-x_2\ge 0$.

Comment: E.Girgin, I deleted my other comment :P

Comment: E.Girgin, how do you know that $$\frac{x_1+1-x_2+x_3}3\le 2/3$$?

Comment: E.Girgin, I edited my question. Do we need to deduce $y_2 = 1-x_2 \ge 0$?